# Python Combobox values not filtering after binding

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, bind

I am working on a project where i need to provide 3 drop down list which should be dependent on each other and should filter values based on selections made on each drop down.
I have used Combobox function in python and have bind them to filter based on selection. This works perfect for the first 2 drop downs, but the 3rd drop down is not showing values as defined to show based on first 2 drop downs.
I am sure i am making some mistake, but not able to find it. Need some expert help.
Below is my sample code which describes my requirement.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root =Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")

sizes =["small","medium","large"]

small_colors = ["red","green"]

medium_colors = ["blue","black"]

large_colors = ["yellow","pink"]

red_numbers = ["one","two"]

green_numbers = ["three","four"]

blue_numbers = ["five","six"]

black_numbers = ["seven","eight"]

yellow_numbers = ["nine","ten"]

pink_numbers = ["eleven","tweleve"]

def pick_color(event):
    if my_combo.get()=="small":
        color_combo.config(value=small_colors)
        color_combo.current(0)
    if my_combo.get()=="medium":
        color_combo.config(value=medium_colors)
        color_combo.current(0)
    if my_combo.get()=="large":
        color_combo.config(value=large_colors)
        color_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="red":
        num_combo.config(value=red_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="yellow":
        num_combo.config(value=yellow_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="green":
        num_combo.config(value=green_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="blue":
        num_combo.config(value=blue_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="black":
        num_combo.config(value=black_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="pink":
        num_combo.config(value=pink_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)

my_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=sizes,state="readonly")
my_combo.current(0)
my_combo.pack(pady=20)
my_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",pick_color)

color_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=[" "],state="readonly")
color_combo.current(0)
color_combo.pack(pady=20)

num_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=[" "], state="readonly")
num_combo.current(0)
num_combo.pack(pady=20)
num_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",pick_color)

def ans():
    print(my_combo.get())
    print(color_combo.get())
    print(num_combo.get())

sub_butn = Button(root, text="SUBMIT", command = ans)
sub_butn.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

its just the 3rd value which is not sorting as expected. When i select "green" in 2nd dropdown it should values as "three","four" in 3rd down down which its not showing.

Comment: else if? you tried? `elif`

Comment: you can make things like that = `options = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]` and put it in your ttk cb `value`.  in your function then `if, elif, elif and else` this `readonly`.method seems to do nothing. do you trying to change a concret color?

Comment: I have tried using `elif` but the 3rd drop down list still dosn't filter the values as expected.

Comment: when we select "small" in 1st drop down and "red" in 2nd drop down the 3rd drop down should show values as "one" and "two" . When we select "small"-"green"  then the 3rd drop down should show "three" and "four".. the first 2 drop down as working as expected.. but not the 3rd one

Comment: i'm not wondering. put it all to one list. if you want 2 or 3 or 5 combos split the list. this is how it works. for exaple. your combo1 has value `small` . .. `if combo1.get() == "small"... `elif combo1 == "red"`... you have 2-5 values in one list. that isn`t the goal of a combobox. regulary you have one value to click on it. if you want more specific maybe you change to radiobuttonns

Comment: i need to use combobox as this is a example of my requirement and my requirement have values beyond 50 hence radiobuttons will not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

This would work. Just replacing `if` with `elif`

```
def pick_color(event):
    if my_combo.get()=="small":
        color_combo.config(value=small_colors)
        color_combo.current(0)
    elif my_combo.get()=="medium":
        color_combo.config(value=medium_colors)
        color_combo.current(0)
    elif my_combo.get()=="large":
        color_combo.config(value=large_colors)
        color_combo.current(0)
    if color_combo.get()=="red":
        num_combo.config(value=red_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    elif color_combo.get()=="yellow":
        num_combo.config(value=yellow_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    elif color_combo.get()=="green":
        num_combo.config(value=green_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    elif color_combo.get()=="blue":
        num_combo.config(value=blue_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    elif color_combo.get()=="black":
        num_combo.config(value=black_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
    elif color_combo.get()=="pink":
        num_combo.config(value=pink_numbers)
        num_combo.current(0)
```

Comment: I did tried with elif option but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: See, the problem is that the first 3 are for ```my_combo.get()``` and the remaining are for ```color_combo.get()``` @k_amit

Answer (score 0):

First you should bind the event on `color_combo`, not `num_combo`.  Second suggest to use different callbacks for `my_combo` and `color_combo`:

```py
def pick_color(event):
    mapping = {
        "small": small_colors,
        "medium": medium_colors,
        "large": large_colors,
    }
    size = my_combo.get()
    if size in mapping:
        # update color_combo
        color_combo.config(value=mapping[size])
        color_combo.set("")
        # clear num_combo
        num_combo.set("")
        num_combo["value"] = []

def pick_number(event):
    mapping = {
        "red": red_numbers,
        "yellow": yellow_numbers,
        "green": green_numbers,
        "blue": blue_numbers,
        "black": black_numbers,
        "pink": pink_numbers,
    }
    color = color_combo.get()
    if color in mapping:
        # update num_combo
        num_combo.config(value=mapping[color])
        num_combo.set("")
...
my_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", pick_color)
...
color_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", pick_number)
...
#num_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",pick_color) # not required
...
```

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 .. this solved my problem.

Comment: @k_amit If it solves your problem, accept it as the answer.